# android.util.Pair container purpose

Tags: java, android, containers

I need to make available two Lists of the same type, let's say `List<Argument>`, pros and cons.

I created a custom Object for that purpose, this way:

```
    public class Decision  {
        private List<Argument> pros;
        private List<Argument> cons;
}
```

and a colleague came across with this solution:

```
Pair<List<Argument>,List<Argument>> decision = new Pair<>(pros,cons);
```

What is the purpose of [Pair](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) if not wrapping up two different objects?

My guess would be something like:

1- Key, value

2- X,Y (coordinates)

3- Something like the example above (pros - cons)

Comment: Pair is a "great obfuscator". It is apparently convenient, because you don't have to create a little class; but it obscures the meaning of the first and second items - are they pros and cons, arguments by you and arguments by your friend, odds and evens, rabbits and dogs? Much better to use a custom object.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Container to ease passing around a tuple of two objects. This object
>   provides a sensible implementation of equals(), returning true if
>   equals() is true on each of the contained objects.

The benefits of `Pair` VS custom wrapper class:

- You don't have to define a class
- Don't have to create `equals`/`hashcode`

The drawbacks are:

- Less clarity with the name `Decision` VS `Pair`
- Less clarity in the fields -> `first` VS `pros` and `second` VS `cons`

Depending on your use case you can choose to use `Pair` or create your own wrapper class.